# Can i change image file size with php?

Tags: php, image-processing

I made a small function to upload images then show them on my website.

My question is now, can I change the file size of a image, on same time as I upload it?

Take facebook as example. Even large images has a size on like 65kb.

If so, witch function should I use?

Thanks,

Comment: PHP's image processing functions might be helpful: http://php.net/manual/en/ref.image.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the [imagecopyresampled](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresampled.php) function:

```
$source_image = imagecreatefromjpeg("youtimagejpg");
$src_w= imagesx($source_image);
$src_h= imagesy($source_image);
$dest_image = imagecreatetruecolor(100, 100); //targeted width and height

imagecopyresampled($dest_image, $source_image, 0, 0, 0, 0, 100, 100, $source_w, $source_h);
imagejpeg($dest_image,NULL,80); 
//Replace null by the path if you want to save on the server, otherwise the image will be sent to the client intead.
```

If you want to reduce the size of the image without resizing it; use the [imagejpeg](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagejpeg.php) function (with a low quality factor)

Answer (score 0):

There are next ways to change image size:

1. Convert to another image format.
2. Save image with lossy compression (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lossy_compression)
3. Resample image with another width & height (http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresampled.php)